# C++ base class reference initialize with different derived class object

Tags: c++, reference, constructor

```c
class Base
{
public:
    void operator()() { func(); }
private:
    virtual void func() {}
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
private:
    void func() override {/*do something*/}
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
private:
    void func() override {/*do something else*/}
};
```

Because I want to use operator overloading,
Reference is a better option than pointer.

What I intend to do is like:

```
if (condition) {
    Base& obj = Derived1();
} else {
    Base& obj = Derived2();
}
```

But obj will be destroyed and end of scope.

```
Base& obj;
if (condition) {
    obj = Derived1();
} else {
    obj = Derived2();
}
```

Will not work either,
Because reference need to be initialized on declaration.

If I try:

```
Base& obj = condition ?
    Derived1() : Derived2();
```

Still an error,
Because ternary operator expect convertible type.

What is the best solution to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not use `?:` in this case as Derived1 and Derived2 are **different types**.

One possible way is to use pointer, this is valid:

```
condition ? pObj.reset(new Derived1()) : pObj.reset(new Derived2());
```

Or

```
#include <memory>
std::unique_ptr<Base> pObj;
if (condition)
{
    pObj.reset(new Derived1());
}
else
{
    pObj.reset(new Derived2());
}
```

You could call `operator()` this way:

```
(*pObj)();
```

Comment: Using pointer means I have to use obj->operator(), and lose the natural syntax of operator overloading.

Comment: see my updated answer, you dont' have to call -> and it doesnt lose operator overloading

Comment: Although this uses pointer, still the best answer for my need.

Comment: And using ternary operator with `unique_ptr::reset()` is neat!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code as below

```
Base *obj1;
if (condition) {
    obj1 = new Derived1();
} else {
    obj1 = new Derived2();
}
Base &obj = *obj1;
```

But make sure you delete obj1 later

Answer (score 1):

If you want the reference, you can't bind a temporary to it unless it's a `const Base &`. This means you need an actual object to bind to, so let's start with that:

```
Derived1 d1;
Derived2 d2;
```

You can, however, get a non-const reference with a function (including a lambda). If lambdas are not available, a normal function would need to take `d1` and `d2` as parameters.

```
auto choose = [&](bool b) -> Base & {
    if (b) {return d1;} 
    else {return d2;}
};
```

Now creating `obj` is easy:

```
Base &obj = choose(condition);
```

Comment: This is actually a working solution, but with redundant object. I'll accept billz's answer as correct one.

Comment: @gnephiak, Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way around that without some kind of pointer. I guess you could technically use a smart pointer and have `Base &obj = *ptr.get();` and then make sure you don't use `obj` after `ptr` goes out of scope.

Comment: If the redundant object is ok (it is on the stack after all), you can just use static_cast instead of the hacky lambda: `Base &obj = condition ? static_cast<Base&>(d1) : static_cast<Base&>(d2);`

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
Base* obj;
if (condition) {
  obj = new Derived1;
} else {
  obj = new Derived2;
}
```

and then at the end of your code you have to add a

```
delete obj
```